# Integral of a semicircle with singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

The problem:

Let $C = \{z \; | \; |z| = R, \; Im(z) ≥ 0\}$ be the semicircle of radius R in the upper
half-plane. Prove that

$\lim_{R→∞} \int_{C} \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2 -2z +2} dz = 0$

My ideas:

we can use the Cauchy's Integral Theorem, which states that if a function $f(z)$ is analytic inside and on a simple closed contour $C$, except at finitely many isolated singularities inside $C$, then the integral of $f(z)$ around $C$ is zero.

In our case, the function $f(z) = \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2 - 2z + 2}$ is analytic everywhere except at the singularities of $z^2 - 2z + 2 = 0$. The singularities:

$z^2 -2z + 2 = 0$

We can solve this quadratic equation by using the quadratic formula, then I get
$1 \pm i$.
Since we are only dealing with the upper half plane of a semicirle, we can omit the $1-i$

So, now I got the singularity. But I'm stuck with regards to how to proceed.

Hope you can help.

Comment: Do your $\gamma$ under the integral mean the semicircle $C$?

Comment: Also, $C = \{z \; | \; |z| = R, \; Im(z) ≥ 0\}$ is not a simple ''closed'' contour. So, you don't need to compute residue or even singularities.

Comment: And you should review Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: @León, Sorry i meant C instead of Gamma. Have edited it now.

Comment: as per the answer below, the estimation lemma can probably be used here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard step in the application of the residue theorem for computing real integrals.

In such a step you shall do an estimate like this:

$$\left|\int_{C}\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2-2z+2}dz\right|\le\int_{C}\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2-2z+2}\right|dz\le \frac{c\pi R}{R^2}=\frac{c\pi}{R}\to0$$
where in the last inequality $\pi R$ is the length of the curve C, and $c/R^2$ comes from the fact that $|z^2-2z+2|$ grows asymptotically like $|z^2|=R^2$

Comment: Thank you! Maybe a stupid question, but what do we gain by taking the integral outside the absolute value of the fraction?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\left|\int_{C}{\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2-2z+2}\, dz}\right|&=\left|\int_{0}^{\pi}{\frac{e^{iR(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)}}{(Re^{i\theta})^2-2Re^{i\theta}+2}iRe^{i\theta}\, d\theta}\right|\\ &\leq\int_{0}^{\pi}{\left|\frac{e^{-R\sin\theta}iRe^{i\theta}}{R^2-2R+2}\right|\, d\theta} \\ &=\frac{2R}{R^2-2R+2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{e^{-R\sin\theta}\, d\theta}\\ &\leq\frac{2R}{R^2-2R+2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{e^{-\frac{2R}{\pi}\theta}\, d\theta}\\ &=\frac{2R}{R^2-2R+2}\left(\frac{\pi-\pi e^{-R}}{2R}\right)=C_R\end{align}$$

$$\lim_{R\to\infty}{C_R}=0$$

Comment: I think like @sb945's answer I could just write the polynomial as $R^2$ but this should work too